# URL with port number giving Time out Error

Tags: php, html, python-2.7, python-3.x, cgihttpserver

I am developing a survey page which also calls a python script. I followed the approach given in https://tasdikrahman.me/2015/10/20/Running-CGI-Scripts-with-CGIHTTPServer/ to set up the folder structure. I activated the URL http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/retrieval.py which works fine on my laptop.

Now, I moved the files on a linux server and Moved all the relevant files within a directory AAA. Upon following the same CGIHTTPServer procedure, I was expecting that the URL would look something like this: http://server1.rciti.edu.au:8000/AAA/cgi-bin/retrieval.py However, when I execute the URL, it gives me a TIME OUT ERROR.

Am I making a big mistake somewhere? The procedure works on my laptop but doesn't on the server. I tried modified URLS too but none of them seems to be working.

I'll really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: We need to see the script(s) or the configurations or something. We can not guess without any information. Also, how is PHP and HTML related here?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to allow and accept 8000 port in the firewall/IPTables.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo